# Techniques/Heuristics for choosing multipliers in method of characteristics for solving PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to solve this linear partial differential equation via method of multipliers.

$$(2y^2+z)z_x+(y+2x)z_y=4xy-z$$

The auxilary Equations are given by:
$$\dfrac{dx}{2y^2+z}=\dfrac{dy}{y+2x}=\dfrac{dz}{4xy-z}=\dfrac{l dx+m dy+n dz}{l(2y^2+z)+m(y+2x)+n (4xy-z)}$$

Letting $(l, m, n)=(1, -2y, 1)$ solves the first part of our problem; giving us $dx-2ydy+dz=0\implies x-y^2+z=c$. This is where I am stuck.

I tried first to find another triplet of $l, m, n$ such that the denominator vanishes on R.H.S. On failing to find such a triplet, I expressed $x$ in terms of $ y $ and $z$ by using $x-y^2+z=c$ and tried to use $dy/..=dz/..$ in order to get the second solution. This ODE I got was very messy and I couldn't continue.

Question:

1) How can another triplet $l, m, n$ be found s.t. denominator on R.H.S. is zero?

2) If not, is there a way to get a simpler ODE?

3) Are there any clever ways to get the multipliers i) in general case ii) When the coefficients of $z_x$ and $z_y$ are polynomials in $x$ and $y$?

4) Is there a deterministic way to solve Linear First Order Partial Differential Equation ? (We have to guess the multipliers in method of multipliers)

Comment: The PDE isn't linear due to the term $zz_x$. Is there a typo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second triplet is : $(l,m,n)=(2x,-z,-y)$ leading to the general solution below :

[image]

Comment: How did you find it?

Comment: @ guest : Well, you obtained the first one. It's the same for the second one. A little bit of gropping, a bit of intuition, a big bit of chance.

Comment: I have to solve these in my exam. I am looking for a systematic approach or at least heuristics to find one.

Comment: The idea is to put the system on the form $\frac{Adx+Bdy+Cdz}{A(2y^2+z)+B(y+2x)+C(4xy-z)}$ and find $A,B,C$ so that $A(2y^2+z)+B(y+2x)+C(4xy-z)=0$. But it's far to be always easy. I suppose that the exercises for students are chosen to be not to too difficult with simple terms $A,B,C$ , sometimes one of them null.

Comment: OKay is there an alternative way for solving such problems?

Comment: I don't think that something simpler exists in the general case. Of course, in more specific cases, with given boundary conditions, they are other approaches depending on the form of the conditions.

Comment: So is there an easier approach in the case of polynomials like this example?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. What polynomial are you thinking of ? Also, you wrote "like this example" : what example ?

Comment: I mean is there an easier approach when PDE is of the form $P(x,y,z)z_x+Q(x,y,z)z_y=R(x,y,z)$ where $P, Q$ and $R$ are polynomials in $x,y,z$

Comment: $P,Q,R$ are polynomials in $(2y^2+z)z_x+(y+2x)z_y=4xy-z$ and I already said that the method shown in my first answer is the easier on my opinion. The same for the general case.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for your time.